# Binding the selected value of radio button to model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, selectedvalue

I have a page view model being used in by Razor view

```
@model Abc.Ecomm.ViewModels.AddressViewModel
```

The `AddressViewModel` does have a property

```
public string AddressId { get; set; }
```

And then I am trying to generate a radio button on the selection of which I need to bind its value to a `AddressId` in my model

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AddressId ,"NA",new { name="" , id="NA"})
```

But when submitted the value is not being bound. 
What am I doing wrong or what could possibly be incorrect?

Comment: The code you have shown will bind fine (although `new { name = "" }` is pointless and should be removed. What is the signature of your POST method (and is it a normal submit or are you using ajax)?

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** The answer below is wrong. I would delete it, but the comments point out an interesting behavior of the ASP.NET MVC framework.

---

When you perform model binding in ASP.NET MVC, it binds the model via the `name` attribute.

You are thwarting this by clearing this attribute explicitly.

Just change it to:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AddressId ,"NA",new { id="NA"})
```

Understand that the HTML form sends the values back to the server as a set of key-value pairs, and each key is the `name` attribute on the corresponding HTML Input control.

Comment: The `new { name="" }` in OP's code does nothing (it does not change the `name` attribute

Comment: @Andrew I did this but still does not work. 
In fact as I do `m => m.` ..... ideally I should get a suggestion drop down in VS2015 .... I am not even getting that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, bad guess on my part. I didn't know that the `name` attribute couldn't be overridden. I'll leave this incorrect answer because it highlights an interesting behavior of the framework.

Comment: That protection is built into the source code (since changing the `name` attribute screws up all other aspects of model binding and should never be done). Unfortunately, the MVC team didn't take case into account and you can 'override' it using `new { Name = ".." }` - but of course it should never be used.

Answer (score 2):

I had the Razor code for the form itself in a partial view with the submit button being in the main view. I moved out the form tag to the the main view to encompass the said radio button and now it is all good.

Elementary mistake.

I am answering this here and keeping this answer alive by accepting it - not just to highlight this mistake but the comments in the answer by Andrew/Stephen  below which sheds light on some overriding behavior and related usage for `@Html.RadioButtonFor`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this please?

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AddressId , 1, new { id = "1"}) 
Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AddressId , 2, new { id = "2"}) 
.......
```